# Separar valores iguais em um array

Tags: php, array

Bom tenho o seguinte array:

```
$produtos2[] = array(
    "cod" => (int) 768,
    "nome" => "LOGITECH M535",
    "GRUPO" => "MOUSE"
);
$produtos2[] = array(
    "cod" => (int) 2334,
    "nome" => "MULTILASER DECT",
    "GRUPO" => "TECLADO"
);
$produtos2[] = array(
    "cod" => (int) 334,
    "nome" => "PANASONIC DECT",
    "GRUPO" => "MOUSE"
);
$produtos2[] = array(
    "cod" => (int) 3334,
    "nome" => "APPLE DECT",
    "GRUPO" => "TECLADO"
);
$produtos2[] = array(
    "cod" => (int) 234,
    "nome" => "SAMSUNG D499",
    "GRUPO" => "MOUSE"
);
```

Para listar o resultado do array eu faço assim:

```
// Navega pelos elementos do array
foreach ($produtos as $c) {

    echo $c['nome']."<br>";
}
```

O resultado é:

```
LOGITECH M535
MULTILASER DECT
PANASONIC DECT
APPLE DECT
SAMSUNG D499
```

Bom o que eu preciso é separar os produtos de tenham o mesmo grupo e listar eles deparando por grupo, exemplo:

```
MOUSE
    LOGITECH M535
    PANASONIC DECT
    SAMSUNG D499

TECLADO
    MULTILASER DECT
    APPLE DECT
```

Não tenho ideia de como fazer isso.

Comment: você pode criar outros array (por grupo) e adcionar os dados do array principal a eles de acordo com o grupo ou transformar em um json e resolver no front-end

Comment: Bom isso é uma boa ideia, posso correr o array de produtos capturando os grupos, porém como evitar a duplicidade de grupo?

Comment: a propriedade grupo é dinâmica? por exemplo pode ser criada mais uma a qualquer momento (daai complica um pouco) ou são opções fixas (nesse caso é só criar `array_teclado` e `array_mouse` e percorrer o array principal passando os itens, seria interessante retirar esses itens do array principal, para não ler mais dados desnecessariamente)

Comment: Ele é dinamico, são vários produtos com vários grupos diferente.

Comment: você possuim alguma tabela no banco onde são cadastrados esses grupos ou o usuário digita num `input` de texto o grupo que quiser?

Comment: o usuário digita num input de texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faça uma função para agrupar:

```
function agrupar($array, $campoAgrupar) {
    $resultado = array();
    foreach($array as $valor) {
        $resultado[$valor[$campoAgrupar]][] = $valor;
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

Agrupando por `"GRUPO"` com a função indicada acima gera-lhe o seguinte array::

```
array(2) {
  ["MOUSE"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cod"]=>
      int(768)
      ["nome"]=>
      string(13) "LOGITECH M535"
      ["GRUPO"]=>
      string(5) "MOUSE"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cod"]=>
      int(334)
      ["nome"]=>
      string(14) "PANASONIC DECT"
      ["GRUPO"]=>
      string(5) "MOUSE"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cod"]=>
      int(234)
      ["nome"]=>
      string(12) "SAMSUNG D499"
      ["GRUPO"]=>
      string(5) "MOUSE"
    }
  }
  ["TECLADO"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cod"]=>
      int(2334)
      ["nome"]=>
      string(15) "MULTILASER DECT"
      ["GRUPO"]=>
      string(7) "TECLADO"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["cod"]=>
      int(3334)
      ["nome"]=>
      string(10) "APPLE DECT"
      ["GRUPO"]=>
      string(7) "TECLADO"
    }
  }
}
```

[Veja no Ideone o resultado do agrupamento](https://ideone.com/kku6VB)

Para o mostrar da forma que pretende basta utilizar dois `foreach`:

```
$produtosPorGrupo = agrupar($produtos2,"GRUPO");

foreach ($produtosPorGrupo as $nomeGrupo => $grupo){
    echo $nomeGrupo . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($grupo as $prod){
        echo "\t" . $prod['nome']. PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

[Veja também no Ideone o resultado já com os 2 `foreach` para mostrar](https://ideone.com/iyrwl6)

Saida final:

```
MOUSE
    LOGITECH M535
    PANASONIC DECT
    SAMSUNG D499
TECLADO
    MULTILASER DECT
    APPLE DECT
```

**Edit**:

Para ordenar pelo array agrupado, basta utilizar uma das funções já existentes no php que ordena pela chave:

- [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ksort.php) - ordenação crescente pela chave
- [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.krsort.php) - ordenação decrescente pela chave

Logo ficaria assim:

```
$produtosPorGrupo = agrupar($produtos2,"GRUPO");    
ksort($produtosPorGrupo);

//resto do código para mostrar
```

Comment: Muito bom, ficou top.

Comment: @HugoBorges Editei a resposta para contemplar a ordenação

Answer (score 4):

Use `array_column()` para obter todos os grupos disponíveis, depois basta fazer um foreach passando o como chave o item atual (grupo) e o valor o item completo.

```
$grupos = array_column($produtos2, 'GRUPO');
$novo = array();
foreach ($produtos2 as $item){
    $novo[$item['GRUPO']][] = $item;
}
```

[Exemplo - idoene](https://ideone.com/wqdojN)

Comment: Vlw, boa solução.